# How to merge and compute the average?

Tags: r

I need to take average of two variables:

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("1/01/2005", "2/01/2005", "3/01/2005", 
"31/12/2005"), x5 = c(52L, 90L, NA, NA),x1 = c(33L, 24L, 72L, 52L)), .Names = 
c("date","x1","x5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(date = c("1/01/2005", "5/04/2006", "13/04/2005", 
"31/12/2005"), x2 = c(20L, 50L, NA, NA), x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
x45 = c(115L, 125L, 127L, 138L)), .Names = c("date", "x2", 
"x3", "x1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

If similar dates exist in both df1 and df2, take the averga of X1: output diserd:

```
     date     x1       
  1/01/2005  83.5      
  31/12/2005 138
```

Comment: You can use `merge` i.e. `newdf <- merge(df1[c('date', 'x1')], df2[c('date', 'x1')], by = 'date'); 
> rowMeans(newdf[-1], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new data.frame marged

```
db_merge<-merge(df1,df2,by.x="date",by.y="date")
```

Mean excluding NA

```
db_merge$x1<-rowMeans(db_merge[,c(2,6)], na.rm=TRUE)
db_merge<-db_merge[,c(1,7)]
```

The Output

```
db_merge
            date    x1
    1  1/01/2005  83.5
    2 31/12/2005 138.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option could be to use `rowwise()` then apply `mean`. This will avoid need to add/mutate a column.

```
df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by="date") %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        group_by(date) %>%
        summarise(x1 = mean(c(x1.x, x1.y), na.rm = TRUE))

The result:
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  date          x1
#  <chr>      <dbl>
#1 1/01/2005   83.5
#2 31/12/2005 138
```